# Who is the parent company of Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, stack-exchange

Just curious who is the parent company of Stack Exchange? My sister wants me to research as practice.

Comment: If your sister wants you to research, maybe you should be searching for answers from a reputable source rather than asking strangers on the internet. ;)

Comment: So, you're asking this because you want to sue them, right?

Answer (score 18):

The Stack Exchange Network sites are owned and operated by Stack Exchange, Inc., which is a privately-owned company - it does not have any parent company.

Comment: So where does litigation go to?

Comment: @Oak If you're going to give the answer rather than letting the asker actually do their own research, you might as well link to the [Terms of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal). _"The Stack Exchange Network (the “Network”) is a set of related Internet sites and other applications for questions and answers, owned and operated by Stack Exchange Inc. (“Stack Exchange”), a Delaware corporation."_

Comment: @GGClassic-Jona52 I don't know, I just answered your immediate question above. If you want more information your best bet is to contact stack exchange directly (see "contact us" below).

Comment: @GGClass I seriously hope that you aren't considering litigation because you're upset about a certain contest...  http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4403/league-of-legends-contest-round-3-final-round

Comment: I don't really know what I am doing.  I was so excited knowing by looking at the small list of people who had asked a question in that time frame with GG Classic somewhere in their profile that I had quadruple all their views.  Just by browsing for 5mins i knew i was second to Res. Just the fact that because a query did not find my question and informing the contest runner literally 3mins after the post was updated and being told that I am ineligible for the separate prize because of one space.  I am just flabbergasted; completely speechless which Is why I am asking around as to where I stand.

Comment: @GGClassic-Jona52 while I do agree that it was a silly technicality that costed you the victory, I'd just chalk it up as a life lesson.  Imagine if she made you the winner, then the other guy who got the prize pointed out the technicality and said he deserved to win because he followed the rules to the letter, while the rules were bent for you how would he feel?

Comment: @GGClassic-Jona52 also, don't forget there will always be other opportunities to win something, why burn bridges?